# Determining NA and Infinite (INF) values from a list that is split and making elements containing INF, NA values NULL

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Hi I have a list which has been split by user. Structure of List is

```
> lst
$A
timestamp user value
2011-01-01 A    1184437
2011-02-01 A    1197000
2011-03-01 A    1483965
2011-04-01 A    1248051
2011-05-01 A    1285838

$B
timestamp user value
2011-01-01 B    12315
2011-02-01 B    12325345
2011-03-01 B    1235223
2011-04-01 B    Inf
2011-05-01 B    Inf

$C
timestamp user value
2011-01-01 C    NA
2011-02-01 C    NA
2011-03-01 C    1181080
2011-04-01 C    1326289
2011-05-01 C    1264455
```

During runtime I want to determine whether any element in the list contains INF or NA value. If yes, then store the name of element someplace else and make that element in the list NULL. I have been trying to use **is.infinite()** for catching INF values but it's not working stating error

```
invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Code Used:

```
NA_names <-  names(lst)[sapply(lst, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) > 0)]    
inf_names <- names(lst)[sapply(lst, function(x) sum(is.infinite(x)) > 0)]
```

Any help or suggestion regarding this? Since sapply works with data frame I'm not sure which method to use.

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(lst)` to your question so the workspace can easily be reproduced by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like a nested `sapply` should work assuming that the list elements are composed of data.frames.

```
# get the list elements that have any infinite value within
keepers <- !sapply(myList, function(i) any(sapply(i, is.infinite)))
keepers
    a     b     c 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE 

# get new list
myNewList <- myList[keepers]

# print names of dropped list items
names(keepers)[keepers]
[1] "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

drops <- map(lst, 'value') %>% # extract the 'value' column from each data.frame
  keep(~ any(!is.finite(.))) %>% # keep only items with non-finite values
  names() # get the names of the remaining list items

lst[drops] <- NULL
```

`purrr::map` works just like `lapply` except that it gives you convenient shortcuts for extracting elements in your list (like using a string to extract columns from a data.frame like in the example). `purrr::keep` iterates over the list and only keeps the elements which satisfy the logical condition you specify.